# HTTP.post() callback in loop

Tags: javascript, http, meteor, callback

I've got a loop of HTTP.post() on my meteor server:

```
for (var i = 0; i < smsMessages.length; i++) {
    HTTP.post("https://smsapiaddress/sms.do", smsMesseges[i], function(error, result) {
        if (error) {
            setErrorInDatabase(smsMessages[i]);
        }
        if (result) {
            setResultInDatabase(smsMessages[i]);
        }
    });
```

How can I easily pass proper smsMessages[i] into the callback function?

Comment: You've got a typo on line 3 `smsMesseges[i]` maybe that's just it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As `http` request is `asynchronous` value of `i` will be shared for all the requests. Use `closures` inside the `for` loop. It will keep a separate copy of `i` for each iteration.

See the comments highlighted in the code:

```
for (var i = 0; i < smsMessages.length; i++) {

    (function(i) {
    // ^^^^^^^^^^^
        HTTP.post("https://smsapiaddress/sms.do", smsMessages[i], function(error, result) {
            if (error) {
                setErrorInDatabase(smsMessages[i]);
            }
            if (result) {
                setResultInDatabase(smsMessages[i]);
            }
        });
    }(i)); // call the function with the current value of i
    // ^^^
}
```